# Two onClick function in one button and want to occur one click function after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Actually i am trying to add a dialog box on the click of a button. But on the OnClick function of that button, i had already called function of a controller. The HTML code for this is:

```
<div class="pro-btn btn">
                        @{
<input type="button" id="place-bid-button-@Model.ProductId" class="button-1"value="@T("Nopaholics.Auction.AuctionDetailView.PlaceBid")" data-   productid="@Model.ProductId" 
onclick="Auction.placeBid('@Url.RouteUrl("Nopaholics.Auction.PlaceBid", new { productId = Model.ProductId, auctionId = Model.AuctionId })', '#product-details-form');return false;" />
}
</div>
```

Now after writing below jquery, both click funtions are working simultaneously. But i want to first confirm by clicking OK button of dialog box and the controller action to be called.

```
<script> 
$('#place-bid-button-'+@Model.ProductId.ToString()).click(function(e){

$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:160,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#place-bid-button-@Model.ProductId.ToString()").click();
            },
            Cancel: function(e) {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $('#place-bid-button-'+@Model.ProductId.ToString()).die();
                console.log(e);
                //return false;
                //e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Remove the `onclick` in the button and run that code in the `"OK": function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); // call Auction.placeBid here ...`

Comment: what is the 2 method that needs to be executed? because i see onclick="Auction.." which is not a razor code(@ is missing). create a js method and call it after the line $( this ).dialog( "close" );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple function. I would recommend too get rid of inline click handler completely.

You can store the url using `data-*` prefixed custom attribute which can be fetched using [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

*HTML*

```
@{
    <input type="button" class="place-bid-button button-1"
            value="@T("Nopaholics.Auction.AuctionDetailView.PlaceBid")" 
            data-url="@Url.RouteUrl("Nopaholics.Auction.PlaceBid", new { productId = Model.ProductId, auctionId = Model.AuctionId })"
            data-form="#product-details-form"/>
}
```

Then you can use following script

```
//Bind click hndler using a common class
$('.place-bid-button').click(function(e) {
    //Store the refrence in a variabled
    var self = this;

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 160,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                //Cal the method with url and form name
                Auction.placeBid(self.dataset.url, self.dataset.form);
                $(this).dialog("close");

            },
            Cancel: function(e) {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried your approach, but on button clicked, it doesn't shown any changes

Comment: No error , but button clik does not show any effect

Comment: @Bijaykushawaha, I have also modified the HTML, Are you using exact code

Comment: Thanks a lot... @Satpal. It really helped me out

Answer (score 0):

Write both the function on single `onclick` attribute like: `onclick="firstFunction();SecondFunction();"`

If you have `confirm/alert` box in firstFunction then.The `confirm/alert` function halts execution of the code until it's dismissed.This mean secondFunction will be called when firstFunction confirm is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform some action on click of button, only if user clicks confirmation dialog to OK ,
  So u need to call the 'ur action method'/action code (which u need to take)on click of 'OK' button of the dialog instead calling 'click()' action explicitly again.